# C++ class with template member that constructs template member with arbitrary template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm not sure why the following code block compiles and works even though the semantics implied by the template syntax are different. Class `A` accepts a template type `Data` and contains a member `data` of template type `Data`. It also has a constructor that accepts an instance of `Data` by value and instantiates the member `data` with the assumed copy constructor. Another class `C` has an arbitrary constructor that takes a pointer to some arbitrary class `B` and stores it as member `foo`. When `Data` in `A` is templated as type `C` and an `A<C>` instantiated with arguments that the constructor for `C` accept (namely, a pointer to a `B`) one would expect a compiler error because `A` has not been told how to handle arbitrary arguments and pass them to the `Data` constructor. It has only been told to use the copy constructor of `Data` with an existing instance. However, this code compiles with clang and c++11 and prints true. I'm assuming this is a compiler bug, not a feature, but perhaps I'm missing something about how C++ templates work? I'm also curious about the correct syntax for this functionality is, (to pass arbitrary template parameters to the constructor for `A` and forward them to the constructor for type `Data`) as that is my actual intent.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename Data>
struct A {
    Data data;
    A(Data data_) : data(data_) { }
};

struct B {
    B() { }
};

struct C {
    B* foo;
    C(B* foo_) : foo(foo_) { }
};

int main() {
    B foo;
    A<C> thing = A<C>(&foo);
    std::cout << (thing.data.foo == &foo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

correct way is [parameter packing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

```cpp
template<typename Data>
struct A {
    Data data;
    template<class ... Args>
    A(Args... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
};

struct B {
    B() { }
};

struct C {
    B* foo;
    C(B* foo_) : foo(foo_) { }
};

int main() {
    B foo;
    A<C> thing = A<C>(&foo);
    std::cout << (thing.data.foo == &foo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you made `A` not a template, this same thing would happen. It's an implicit conversion

Comment: Interesting, just tried this and you're totally right. Seems very odd to me is there documentation on this functionality somewhere?

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) isn't exactly the easiest to read, but it's very accurate.

Comment: @Justin Please expand this to an answer. Otherwise, we only have the poor attempt by a rat.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code compiles is because your constructor for `struct C` is not flagged as explicit. In effect, `A<C>` object expects a `C` object in its constructor. But you provide a pointer to b instead. Since none of your single parameter ctors are flagged as explicit, it is legal for the compiler to choose an appropriate conversion from input parameter to the desired parameter.

Usually static code analyzers will flag this as undesirable as you don't ever want automatic or unexpected conversions of this sort. So you really should flag all single parameter ctors with the explicit keyword.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit